# Get window title from controller

Tags: java, javafx

So I was wondering if it is possible to get the window title (like shown on the image) into a string from the controller. 
[image: The image]

Comment: Note that for the approach presented in the linked question you can also use an injected node that is part of the scene...

Answer (score 1):

The title of an JavaFx-Application is set in the class `javafx.stage.Stage` via `stage.setTitle("hello world");`.

That means that you can get the title of your stage via `stage.getTitle();`.

To get your stage, you could do something like this:
Assuming that you have your starting class named `Main` and a controller with a method `doSomething`.

In your class `Main`, you can save your complete stage.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("hello World");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

That means that your starting stage (`primaryStage`) is saved in the variable `stage`.

In your controller, you can easily get your stage (and the title) by calling the getter.

```
public void doSomething() {
    String title = Main.getStage().getTitle();
    //  some other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[getTitle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getTitle--) method will give a window title String.